# Does the execution flow of a method wait when you call another method within it?

Tags: java, oop, execution

Say you have the following method in `MyClass`

```
public class MyClas{
  public void startWork(){
    YourClass.doSomeWork();
    //more things to do in this method
  }
}
```

and YourClass looks like this:

```
public class YourClass{
  public static void doSomeWork(){
    // a lot of work to do here
    // maybe even invoke other methods in some other classes
  }
}
```

now what I am wondering is when the code `YourClass.doSomeWork();` is executed in `startWork()` method, will the script continue to the next line in the same method or wait until `doSomeWork()` in `YourClass` finishes its execution?

Note that `doSomeWork()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: It will wait. Did you do some research? Did you try executing your code?

Comment: Execution is sequential in a single thread of execution.

Comment: It is like putting the code of the called method directly into the calling method. So yes, it will definitely be executed entirely before going on with the calling method. Different behaviour will occur while multithreading.

Comment: Thank you very much for the inputs everyone. @BackSlash yes I did some research but couldn't find a clear answer like the ones I just got here. I did try to execute the code but it executes so fast and I couldn't figure out whether it was waiting or not.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback, although I agree, pretty basic stuff this is ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *default* semantics in most languages, and especially in Java is of course that code gets executed sequentially.

Meaning: unless you do *additional* things, such as submitting a task into an ExecutorService (or creating a Thread object and calling its `start()` method), then *of course* an outer method will execute all calls in sequence, and each inner call needs to finish before the next one is executed.

In other words: unless you use specific constructs in your source code, things get executed by a single thread, in the exact order that you put in your code. And yes, things can get more complicated, as instructions can be re-ordered at various levels, but these aspects of the Java memory model aren't relevant for the basic question asked here).

Answer (score 5):

It will wait until `doSomeWork` finished.

If you want to call `doSomeWork` asynchronouly and the next procedure of `startWork` does not rely on the result of `doSomeWork`, you can take use of some concurrent framework, for example, [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).